# Splitting of angle in triangle

Tags: geometry

I got the following definition of what an angle between the points A B C in the 2 dimensional euclidean plane is.
$$angle(A, B, C) := arccos ((A-B, C-B) / (||A-B|| * ||C-B||))$$

For this definition I want to *formally* prove that:

lemma:
If $P \in convex hull \{A, B, C\}"$ then
$$angle(A, B, C) = angle(A, B, P) + angle(P, B, C)$$

I know that I can translate my whole situation, so that B is the
origin to obtain a simpler equation. I can even rotate the situation,
so that one of A, C or P have one zero component. Then I tried to look at a
convex combination of P, but I have not succeeded to find an answer.
Have I overseen something, how would a valid proof of this lemma look like.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a formal proof. OK. Do you want a proof based on the Euclidean axioms of geometry? Or do you want a proof based on the properties of vectors? Do you want a proof based on coordinate geometry?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I would prefer not to use the Euclidean axioms of geometry, but to restrict myself to the theory of vectors, coordinate geometry, the theory of convex sets and trigonometry. I would also highly appreciate proof sketches and work out the pesky formal details on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one understands that $$\operatorname {angle}(A, B, C) := \operatorname{arccos} \left(\frac{(A-B, C-B) } {||A-B|| \cdot ||C-B||}\right)$$
computes the angle in blue shown in figure (a) below

[image]

then the one will understand how to compute the red angles shown in figures (b) and (c).

The sum of the red angles equals the blue one.